# How do I set a color other than black to image created with makeTransparent()

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, gdi

I am using the `MakeTransparent()` function call on the c# Bitmap object to convert images to transparent images. When this method is called, it will convert a background color to be transparent by setting the alpha channel, but it then converts the background color to black.

I need to find a fast way of converting this background color back to white or whatever the original color was, as occasionally I need to flatten the image to a non-alpha channel enabled format.

Make transparent doesn't seem to have any flags or overloads that allows you to tell it to leave the background color alone, and altering the image pixel by pixel is way to inefficient.  Anyone have any suggestions or GDI tricks to solve this problem?

Comment: It is an internal optimization that you'll have to deal with.  If you want the background to be white then just draw it on a white background.  If you want to restore the original background color then you'll have to remember what it was.

Comment: I can write a function to flatten the image with a background, but it seems like there should be a simpler solution.

Comment: Simply don't use the function then. Do it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a fast way to do this using the managed code interface. Using individual pixel manipulation, or using unmanaged code to update the pixels seem to be the only real options.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually possible in managed code, by using `Marshal.Copy` to copy the backing byte array out of a bitmap object, then editing it, and then copying it back.

So basically, with that general method in mind, you just go over the pixels, line by line, detect which pixels have the colour you want replaced, and set their alpha byte to 0.

Note that "ARGB" refers to the order of the components inside the `Int32` value of one read pixel. Since this value is little-endian, the actual order of the bytes at a given offset is the reverse; B = offset + 0, G = offset + 1, R = offset + 2, A = offset + 3.

```
/// <summary>
/// Clears the alpha value of all pixels matching the given colour.
/// </summary>
public static Bitmap MakeTransparentKeepColour(Bitmap image, Color clearColour)
{
    Int32 width = image.Width;
    Int32 height = image.Height;
    // Paint on 32bppargb, so we're sure of the byte data format
    Bitmap bm32 = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bm32))
        gr.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height));

    BitmapData sourceData = bm32.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bm32.PixelFormat);
    Int32 stride = sourceData.Stride;
    // Copy the image data into a local array so we can use managed functions to manipulate it.
    Byte[] data = new Byte[stride * height];
    Marshal.Copy(sourceData.Scan0, data, 0, data.Length);
    Byte colR = clearColour.R;
    Byte colG = clearColour.G;
    Byte colB = clearColour.B;
    for (Int32 y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        Int32 inputOffs = y * stride;
        for (Int32 x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            if (data[inputOffs + 2] == colR && data[inputOffs + 1] == colG && data[inputOffs] == colB)
                data[inputOffs + 3] = 0;
            inputOffs += 4;
        }
    }
    // Copy the edited image data back.
    Marshal.Copy(data, 0, sourceData.Scan0, data.Length);
    bm32.UnlockBits(sourceData);
    return bm32;
}
```

This can easily be enhanced with a tolerance level instead of an exact match, with something like `Math.Abs(data[inputOffs + 2] - colR) < tolerance`, or by actually converting the bytes to a colour object and doing some other kind of approximation (like hue/saturation/brightness).